# powershell create txt files based on csv file

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach

I have csv file with list of filepaths:

```
Filename 
C:\Users\postgres\1.tmp 
C:\Users\postgres222\2.txt
C:\Users\postgres3333\3.jpeg
```

I would like to loop through that list and to create in the same directory txt file per every file with below information:
Today's date
Filepath
Name of file

so in example for 1st file it should be file `C:\Users\postgres\1.tmp.txt`
with data:

```
03\11\2021
C:\Users\postgres\1.tmp 
1.tmp
```

I tried:

```
$Time=Get-date
$data = "\mydir"
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $data){New-Item -ItemType file -Path $Get-Item $file.Fullpath + ".txt" -Value $Time Add-Content $Get-Item $file.Fullpath}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: updated original

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Import-Csv` on the input file and loop through the data with `ForEach-Object`.
Inside the loop, split the fullname into the path and the filename only:

```
$today = '{0:dd\\MM\\yyyy}' -f (Get-Date)
(Import-Csv -Path 'X:\Path\Folder\Input.csv').Filename | ForEach-Object {
    $path = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_)   # or use: Split-Path $_ -Parent
    $file = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_)        # or use: Split-Path $_ -Leaf
    # create the full path and filename for the output
    $out  = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ('{0}.txt' -f $file)
    # construct the three lines and write the file
    "$today`r`n$_`r`n$file" | Set-Content -Path $out
}
```